# How to calculate timeline interval width?

Tags: javascript, wavesurfer.js

How can I calculate the width of the timeline's interval in pixels.

[image: Screenshot 2023-03-04 170521]

I am using these options in timeline plugin:

```js
container: "#wave-timeline",
height: 40,
timeInterval: this.timeInterval,
secondaryLabelInterval: 1,
```

```js
function timeInterval(pxPerSec) {
    return (200 / pxPerSec) 
}
```

Note: I am using zoom in/out with the timeline